# PHP: Searching for "a.."

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to make so when you search e.g "A" then every full_name with beginning "A" will appear.
So if a user with name "Andreas blabla" will show

I have this right now:

```
$query = "SELECT full_name, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort 
              FROM users WHERE full_name LIKE '$_GET[searchUser]'";
```

But still i need to search "Andreas blabla" in order to get him out the query(show). So this doesnt work.

How can i do this?

Comment: remember to format this string by using mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchUser']) or by using parametrized query

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%` meta character after the input character in the [`LIKE` comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
$query = " … WHERE full_name LIKE '$_GET[searchUser]%'";
```

And don’t forget to validate the input or escape the output properly when inserting it into the query.

Answer (score 2):

It seems complete code would be better than just comment

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchUser']);
$query = "SELECT full_name, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort 
          FROM users WHERE full_name LIKE '$search%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MySql wildcards like:

`$query = "SELECT full_name, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE full_name LIKE '$_GET[searchUser]%'";`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
...LIKE '$_GET[searchUser]%'";
```

If the user searches for `A`, this will select all rows where `full_name` begins with an `A`

`%` is a wild card to match anything.